# Calculating Formula for days and text

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, conversion

Trying to write a formula that calculates the expected completion date based on the priority of the project day it was assigned.

For two of the priorities, it needs to be a text response in the calculated column. Current formula as follows:

=if([Priority]="Critical"),[Delivery Date] + 10, if([Priority]="High"), [Delivery Date] + 25, if([Priority]="Medium", [Delivery Date] + 65, if([Priority]="Low", "Next major version", if([Priority]="Informational", "Informational"))))

I'm trying to say, if priority is high, add 10 days to the delivery date (delivery date is when it was assigned). I want to know the due date. Since there is text in the formula, how do I get this to show as a text field, provide the dates for the 3 priority items (Critical, High, Medium) that need dates and generate the text for low and informational?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the date values into text, you can use the `TEXT(Date, Format)` function for that.

You also had some parentheses on the loose, it helps to type the formulas out like this:

```
=if([Priority]="Critical", TEXT([Delivery Date] + 10,"yyyy-mm-dd"), 
    if([Priority]="High", TEXT([Delivery Date] + 25,"yyyy-mm-dd"), 
        if([Priority]="Medium", TEXT([Delivery Date] + 65,"yyyy-mm-dd"), 
            if([Priority]="Low", "Next major version", 
                if([Priority]="Branch E", "Informational","Unexpected Value")
            )
        )
    )
)
```